# Extract a range from multiple rows in a table and combine into one

Tags: r

I have a table with excavation data. It lists Items from features and a corresponding date range. Like this:

```
feature_id   object_type_id    amount    date_id    chronology
156          46                3          3          2300-2200
156          46                3          4          2200-2100
156          46                3          5          2100-2000
274          37                1          4          2200-2100
274          37                1          5          2100-2000
```

As you see the table is very redundant. I would like to clean it up in a way that gives me just one row per object_type_id per feature_id an replaces all the chronology and date_id hassle with a start and a stop time. e.g:

```
feature_id    object_type_id    amount   start_chronology    stop_chronology
156           46                3        2300                2000
```

How can I archive this? I'm puzzled and lost.

Comment: *per object_type_id per feature_id*...yet your desired output only has one *feature_id* and one *object_type_id* despite input having two each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the per *feature_id* and *object_type_id*, consider splitting *chronology* column by hyphen in `within`, then calling `aggregate` where you pass two columns to run two functions with final column cleanup at end.

```
# ASSIGN NEW COLS TO SPLIT chronology
df <- within(df, { 
              chronology <- as.character(chronology)
              start_chronology <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(chronology, '-'), `[`, 1))
              stop_chronology <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(chronology, '-'), `[`, 2))
              date_id <- NULL
              chronology <- NULL
      })
df
#   feature_id object_type_id amount start_chronology stop_chronology
# 1        156             46      3             2300            2200
# 2        156             46      3             2200            2100
# 3        156             46      3             2100            2000
# 4        274             37      1             2200            2100
# 5        274             37      1             2100            2000

# AGGREGATE TWO COLS ALONG TWO FCTS
agg_df <- do.call(data.frame,
                  aggregate(cbind(start_chronology, stop_chronology) ~ feature_id + object_type_id + amount, df, 
                            function(x) c(min=min(x), max=max(x)))
                  )

# REMOVE COLS AND RENAME COLS
agg_df <- setNames(transform(agg_df, start_chronology.min = NULL, stop_chronology.max=NULL), names(df))
agg_df

#   feature_id object_type_id amount start_chronology stop_chronology
# 1        274             37      1             2200            2000
# 2        156             46      3             2300            2000
```

Comment: I get the following error code:
 
    Error in strsplit(df$chronology, "-") : non-character argument

Comment: You need to cast the column with `as.character()` from factor.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to do with the **tidyverse** package:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'feature_id   object_type_id    amount    date_id    chronology
156          46                3          3          2300-2200
                 156          46                3          4          2200-2100
                 156          46                3          5          2100-2000
                 274          37                1          4          2200-2100
                 274          37                1          5          2100-2000', header = T)

library(tidyverse)

df.new <- df %>% 
  separate(chronology, c('start', 'end')) %>% 
  group_by(feature_id, object_type_id) %>% 
  summarize(
    amount = unique(amount),
    start_chronology = max(start),
    stop_chronology = min(end)
  )

  feature_id object_type_id amount start_chronology stop_chronology
       <int>          <int>  <int> <chr>            <chr>          
1        156             46      3 2300             2000           
2        274             37      1 2200             2000
```